# TV show from 2000s where a group of kids were put in a digital version of the real world

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

There was this TV show I remember watching as a kid, but I can’t recall the name. I know it’s not *MP4orce* or *Chaotic*, I only remember very little about it.

The premise was these group of kids would get put in a digitized version of the world. Where one of them, a female, would have to reach this tower, I think it was pink, in order to reset everything.

There was one episode in particular I remember where the person they’re supposed to get to the tower enters a fake one and it disrupts the reset.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you tell us anything about the animation style or specific details of the characters (hair colour, etc.)?  Was the art different between the digital world and the "real" world?

Answer (score 5):

This has to be Code Lyoko. The [wiki](https://codelyoko.fandom.com/wiki/Tower) identifies an episode with a fake tower:

> At the end of Garage Kids multiple Towers are seen close to each other, but in Code Lyoko, Towers are not normally close to each other unless X.A.N.A. creates a fake one to confuse the group, as seen in **End of Take**.

Aelita deactivating a tower, from the wiki:

[image: her hand to a control panel that looks like a lighted rectangle floating in the air]